# Grid View layout

Tags: android, image, gridview

[image]

I want to use the grid view in which first image is constant and on the click want to launch addProductActivity for all user , and after that the images from server will be displayed. How to achieve this please help.

Comment: What did you try? Why a GridLayout and not a GridView?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein yes am using GridView, and am not getting any idea how to achieve this please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by `recyclerview` where you can give layout manager as `gridlayout` manager :

```
 RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.fridID);
 Adapter gridAdapter = new Adapter(yourProductArray, getContext(), this, this);
 GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3);
 mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
 mRecyclerView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
```

- and at the recyclerview `Adapter` when position is zero in `onBindViewHolder(Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position)`, always show the constant image
- You can set `onClickListener` to the `ImageView` and when the position is zero and `onClickListener` is triggered show the add product screen
- when a new product is added add the product to the `yourProductArray` and use `gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`